# Undefined method for nil:NilClass. Can't access to user's name or any other data when calling from another controller in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" when I'm trying to get the users name of a comment from the articles controller. I've tryed to do the same request from the comments controller and it works just fine.

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show
Showing    C:/xampp/htdocs/app/views/comments/_show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I' using ruby -v 2.1.5 and rails -v 4.2.2

Here is my comments controller code:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

def show
    @comments= Comment.all
end

def new
    @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end


end 

private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

And my Articles controller code

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]



def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @user = @article.user
    @comments = @article.comments
end

...

private

  def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :lead, :content, :hashtags,  :front_picture, :category_id, :league_id, :front_pic_src)
  end
end
```

And the views:

/articles => show

```
<!-- A little peace of my Articles view where I use "user" but under the @article -->
<h3> Article Autor</h3>
    <div id="about-info">
        <div class="post-profile-img-wrapper">
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(@article.user, size: 50), @article.user %>
        </div>
        <span class="user"><%= link_to @article.user.name, @article.user %>  </span>
    </div>

<!-- And here I call the render for comments-->
<section class="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
      <%= render 'comments/show' %>
</section>
```

And the rendered partial is _show.html.erb inside the comments view

```
<% @comments.each do|c| %>
 <h1><%= c.user.name %></h1>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tryed to create an instance variable in articles for user comments and it doesn't work.

The comments table has a foreing key but it's pointing to the article_id I don't know if this is the best way, but it shouldn't affect the controllers behaviour, right?

UPDATE

Here is my comments schema, it may help

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "body",       limit: 65535
t.integer  "article_id", limit: 4
t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 4
t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
end

add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id", using: :btree
add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using:   :btree
```

UPDATE FOR Models
Comment:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article  
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :body, presence: true

end
```

Article:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :league
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
mount_uploader :front_picture, ArticleFrontUploader
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :category_id, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true
#validate  :picture_size

private

# Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
    def picture_size
        if front_picture.size > 5.megabytes
          errors.add(:front_picture, "should be less than 5MB")
        end
    end


 end
```

Related peace of user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to clean up this post A LOT just to make it more readable. If possible, use pastebin or gist.

Answer (score 1):

## STEP ONE: Setting up a partial

You can try naming local variables when rendering a partial. For example, in `/articles/_show.html.erb`, you would enter the following at the (current) rendering line:

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/show', locals: {comments: @comments} %>
```

That will treat the `/comments/_show.html.erb` as a piece of a page, rather than a complete one. This is ideal for your situation, since the page itself is about articles, but you only want to render *a part* of the page to show comments.

The `locals` hash sets up variables so your partial can render the correct objects, assuming they are named in the current controller. (In this case, the current controller is `ArticlesController`.) After setting local values, your next step in the comments show page is to replace `@comments` with simply `comments`.

Now, say you have no comments associated with the article. It is the same as `Comment.where(article_id: @article.id)`, which is an array. Calling `each` on an empty array will take the first element, pretty much nil, and raise an error. In the app I work on, the best way to handle this is to prepend the code block with the following:

```
unless comments.empty?
```

This makes sense, because why show contents for comments if there are none present? Mind you, if you plan to have a form for entering comments, place that form *outside* the `unless` statement, and below the comments show partial.

## STEP TWO: Editing associations

I do not know how you want to set this up exactly, so rather than provide copy/paste code, I will just explain. In most cases, comments do not stand alone, they always belong to something. A comment *immediately* belongs to an article. In your models, your associations should have a user having a comment *through* an article. Given the code you provided, I believe the hierarcy is the following:

```
User
Article
Comment
```

You need a user to make an article. You need an article to make a comment. While a user is required to make a comment, it is not a direct association. Again, I will not provide you with the exact code, as you may want to handle this slightly differently, but along the same lines.

Comment: Hi @onebree thanks for your help! But doing this I get:  undefined method `user' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0xaacbdb8>

Comment: I can help you out later, if you do not mind. I think the issue lies in the model associations, which you should show instead of the schema, in my opinion

Comment: it's like the association is broken somewhere but I can get the object itself and I can link to the user. I just can't access to the users table information from comments

Comment: That is why I said to post the models of the article/comment/user and the associations you name.

Comment: @NachPD I will check out everything tonight. I definitely think partials/locals are necessary, but the issue lies in your associations. Are you, by chance, doing this from the Rails Guides tutorial? I suggest following that for further advice while I am gone. Much of your code resembles the guide's tutorial

Comment: Thanks @onebree I've read the rails guide and Michael Hartl's book and other few books and my code it's a remix of them. I'm agree that we're facing an association issue but I can't see where I'm wrong, an object can belong to more than one object and I wrote it. You're being very helpful , thanks!!

Comment: @NachPD I updated my answer to help with associations

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the `_show.html.erb` in the comments view. The comment has only a **user_id** attribute. So if you call `@comment.user` there is nothing to show since the comment doesn't have **user** attribute. You have to search for the user by the **user_id**

```
<% @comments.each do |c| %>
  <h1><%= User.find_by_id(c.user_id).name %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Try this. It would solve the problem.

Comment: This is not preferable, as you want as little logic as possible in the view. You want to make all your queries once in the controller to cache them, as now this query searches through ALL users to find one matching.

Comment: True enough but I think this is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `locals` to `partial`

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/show', locals: { comments: @comments } %>
```

comments/_show.html.erb

```
<% comments.each do|c| %>
  <h1><%= c.try(:user).try(:name) %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @prashant4020 that worked for me! But why we have to access with try?  In the model, I'm posting it after finish this comment, comments belongs to user, so I should have access to the user's data right? Thanks for your help

Comment: But why is try working and the simple call not? Thanks